# What to eat to gain strength in one hour to compensate for going hungry for a week?

Tags: strength, workout, weight-gain

For the past week I have been eating about 200 calories a day to lose weight for a wrestling meet tomorrow. As a result I have dropped 5 pounds in the last week but do not feel at my full strength. I am 17 and weigh about 140 pounds.

What should I eat tomorrow after weigh ins (Exactly one hour before wrestling) to have the most strength possible and feel good during the match?

Comment: Cutting weight is not natural and is counter productive towards your success as an athlete.  It's dangerous.  Keep that in mind, and I certainly hope your coach isn't pushing for you to cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely to be

1. dehydrated
2. glycogen depleted
3. in hyperketonemia

Short term solution?

1. Drink water.
2. Eat sugar and other carbohydrates that are rapidly metabolized.
3. Caffeine.
4. Do not eat protein or fat--it won't help.

If you'll be exerting yourself for several hours, you should keep eating small amounts throughout that time period.  For several days after the match, you will need to eat full, balanced meals.  Needless to say I don't think that fasting for a week is a good idea, health-wise.

Answer (score 2):

My after-weigh-in package included a small grilled chicken breast and a well-cooked sweet potato with butter, eaten slowly. That worked pretty great. I also drank plenty of water, though juices would also be reasonable. Dairy would be ill-advised, as would any fried foods or other foods that give you difficulty with digestion.